# Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: <Corrections Technology> in line 9

Tags: php

I am facing some problem with the code please help me.. I would be very grateful to you..

```
$category = '
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<document> 

 <Astronomy>
   <items>milky way, comet</items> 
 </Astronomy> 

 <Business>
   <items>abilities, accelerated benefits</items> 
 </Business> 

<Corrections Technology>
   <items>accomplice, addiction, agent</items> 
</Corrections Technology> 

</document>';


$category = simplexml_load_string($category);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Corrections Technology>` is an invalid xml tag

You cannot have space in the tag name. [See Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-NameChar)